# Is there a shell that has tabs that you can use with mingw?

Tags: mingw

I don't mean tabbed completion. 
I mean tabs like what firefox, chrome etc have, that you can switch between.

Answer (score 8):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you're looking for a tabbed interface for multiple bash shells, right?  If so, you could use [Console2](http://console.sourceforge.net) to host your mingw windows.  I use it for Cygwin and it works great!  Just configure each tab in Console2 to start the MinGW bash shell.

Comment: yes, that's what I meant. I will try console2, Thanks.

Comment: Just tried it, as of 2019 on Windows 10, it looks like when I set up Console2 to open `msys2.exe`, msys2 opens in a new window regardless (it does not open in a Console2 tab); [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/) seems to be an alternative

Answer (score 1):

GNU [screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) would do what you want, but a quick Google search seems to indicate that there's not currently a Cygwin or mingw build of the tool.