# ConEmu: How to call msys2 Portable as tab?

Tags: conemu, portable-apps, msys, terminal-emulator

I mean to have several tabbed Msys2 terminals, all portable.

[Is there a shell that has tabs that you can use with mingw?](https://superuser.com/questions/95076/is-there-a-shell-that-has-tabs-that-you-can-use-with-mingw)
suggests console2, but I could not find a portable version (**if there is a portable version, it would also be a useful answer!**).

Then I considered ConEmu from [here](https://www.slant.co/options/5490/alternatives/~console2-alternatives).
[This](https://conemu.github.io/en/CygwinMsys.html#cygwin-connector) further indicates it can be done.

[ConEmu: How to call msys2 as tab?](https://superuser.com/questions/1024301/conemu-how-to-call-msys2-as-tab)
asks about launching Msys2. But that uses the non-portable version.

In my case, the executable is 
`<mydir>\MSYS2Portable\MinGW64Portable.exe`.

If I use `<mydir>\MSYS2Portable\MinGW64Portable.exe -new_console`, it creates a `cmd` tab, and a tiny MinGW window (with actually only a narrow title bar), which then stays in the background but is useless.

If I use `cmd /A /Q /K "<mydir>\PortableApps\MSYS2Portable\MinGW64Portable.exe" -new_console`, it creates a `cmd` tab, and a separate working MinGW terminal (same as if I launched it from PortableApps).

The only way I found to have a tabbed terminal is using `<mydir>\MSYS2Portable\App\msys32\usr\bin\bash.exe --login -i -new_console`, which only changes my colors from the regular non-tabbed terminal (including those explicitly set in a colored prompt).
I have nothing against this, but...

**Is there a way to get the tabbed terminal calling `MinGW64Portable.exe`, or an alternative from within the directory of the portable app, which behaves exactly the same as running `MinGW64Portable.exe` outside the tabbed environment?**

I am assuming what I did does not behave *exactly the same* (I did not identify differences so far, other than color as said). If `<mydir>\MSYS2Portable\MinGW64Portable.exe` only did `<mydir>\MSYS2Portable\App\msys32\usr\bin\bash.exe --login -i`, it seems to me it means that there would be a lot of superfluous files).

Comment: MinGW64Portable.exe is not a console application

Comment: @Maximus - Please see updated boldface question... I do not care about using specifically *that* executable.

Comment: I don't understand the question because you already `have a tabbed terminal is using <mydir>\MSYS2Portable\App\msys32\usr\bin\bash.exe --login -i`

Comment: @Maximus - I understand your point. Please see updated boldface question and following text.